# yeoman, grunt - how add a banner to my generated files

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I created a mobile application with the yeoman mobile-generator. 
I'am very new to grunt and yeoman, but it's really awesome stuff!
Does anyone know what I have to do add a banner to my generated files?

```
   meta: {
        version: '0.1.0',
        banner: '/*! PROJECT_NAME - v<%= meta.version %> - ' +
            '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
            '* http://PROJECT_WEBSITE/\n' +
            '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> ' +
            'MyName; Licensed MIT */'
    },
```

Where I have to use this. I have tried something like this, but does not affect.

```
    usemin: {
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        },
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<banner:meta.banner>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },
```

...

```
    cssmin: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                    '<banner:meta.banner>', 
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Banners go in the options object:

```
cssmin: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            banner: '<%= meta.banner %>'
        },
        files: {
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Hat tip: I'd also use the metadata in `package.json`, that way you save duplicating it in your Gruntfile, and you can also reuse that banner config for other projects without having to change it.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // pkg: grunt.file.read('package.json'),
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
            '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
            '* http://<%= pkg.homepage %>/\n' +
            '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> ' +
            '<%= pkg.author.name %>; Licensed MIT */',
    cssmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                banner: '<%= banner %>'
            },
            files: {
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    // rest of your config...
});
```

And in `package.json`:

```
{
    "name":                         "project name",
    "version":                      "0.1.0",
    "homepage":                     "https://stackoverflow.com",
    "author": {
        "name":                     "your name",
        "email":                    "your email",
        "url":                      "your website"
    }
    // devDependencies, etc
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for this! Works great with the chage of this line: "pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),"

Comment: one question, where I have to put this when I also would have the banner in my main.js (now it is only in the css) file?

Comment: `grunt-contrib-uglify` takes a banner as one of its options, so you'd do something like `uglify: { dist: { options: { banner: '<%= banner %>' } // rest of config } }`. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#banner

Comment: Worth noting that CSSMin no longer supports the `banner` option